# Where can I find estimates of CARA risk aversion

Tags: reference-request, finance, risk-aversion

I'm trying to get a sense of what levels of CARA risk aversion are typically considered "reasonable" in the literature for American consumers. Can someone point me to some papers that estimate CARA parameters?

I'll take answers regarding CRRA as well.

Comment: maybe this one here can help?
https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/empirical-estimates-of-crra-and-cara-utility?rq=1